# A decomposition involving a Bayesian belief network

Tags: probability

I am reading Chapter $3.9$ of Duda and Hart's *Pattern Classification*.

In a particular example, we take a node $X$ of a Bayesian belief network where each node can take on a set of discrete states, and I am trying to understand the equality below, where $X$ is a node in the DAG, $e^P$ is the evidence  on the parent nodes of $X$, and $P_{m,n}$ denotes a particular value for state $n$ on parent node $P_m$

$$ p (x|e^{P} ) 
= p (x|e^{P_1} , e^{P_2} , \ldots,  e^{P_{|P|}} )
$$ $$= \sum_{\text{all }(i, j, \ldots, k)}
p (x|P_{1i} , P_{2j} , ..., P_{|P|k} )p (P_{1i} , P_{2j} , \ldots, P_{|P|k} |e^{P_1} , \ldots , e^{P_|P|} )$$

I can't tell if this is a consequence of Bayes theorem, or something to do with conditional independence, or even some equality like for discrete random variables $A, B, C$ that $p(a|b) = \sum_{c \in C} p(a|c) p(c|b)$. Any insights how this equality is achieved much appreciated.

Comment: I have not studied belief networks but $p(a|b) = \sum_{c \in C} p(a|c) p(c|b)$ follows from the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and the Markov property (which I assume these networks abide by).

Comment: @Mevve the networks satisfy that nodes that are not connected (no path connects one node to another) represent variables that are conditionally independent of each other. I'm not sure if this relates directly to the Markov property that nodes are only conditionally dependent on their immediate parents.

Comment: If they are conditionally independent then the sum still follows from the law of total probability (and Bayes theorem).

Comment: @Mevve if you could elaborate in an answer I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Bayes theorem gives us
$P(a|b) = \frac{P(a,b)}{P(b)}$.
From the law of total probability and repeated use of Bayes theorem we get

$$\begin{align} P(a|b) = \frac{P(a,b)}{P(b)}
&= \frac{1}{P(b)} \sum_{c \in C} P(a,b,c) \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{1}{P(b)} \sum_{c \in C} P(a|b,c)P(b,c) \tag{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{P(b)} \sum_{c \in C} P(a|b,c) \cdot P(c|b)P(b) \tag{3} \\
&= \sum_{c \in C} P(a|c)P(c|b) \tag{4} \end{align} $$

Where we used the law of total prob in (1), Bayes theorem in (2) and (3) and conditional independence in (4).